# Weak topology on vector space $(B,k)$ is generated by the sets $\{\mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon} \mid \phi \in B^*,v \in B,\epsilon>0\}\,$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Show that the weak topology on $B$, a vector space over $k$, is generated by $$\{\mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon} \mid \phi \in B^*,v \in B,\epsilon>0\},\,\, \text{ where } \mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon}=\{w \in B \mid |\phi(w)-\phi(v)|<\epsilon\}.$$

*Attempt:* I will try to show that for any open set $U$ in the weak topology, and $x \in U$, we can find some $\mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon}$ containing $x$ contained in $U$. Let $U$ be open in the weak topology. By definition $U=\phi^{-1}(V)$ for some $\phi \in B^*$ and $V$ open in $k$. Since $V$ is open for each $y \in V$ there exists $r>0$ such that $B(r,y) \subset V$. So that $\phi^{-1}(B(r,y))\subset U$. Let $x$ be a point mapping to $\phi(y)$. Since $\phi^{-1}(B(r,y))$ is open there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $B(\epsilon,x) \subset \phi^{-1}(B(r,y))$. Then $\mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon} \subset U$.

Is this in the right direction? If not, how can I do this? Or should I try to show that finite intersections of the $\mathcal{N}$'s generate the topology? Since the collection is only a subbase?

Comment: That's the gist, except you want to phrase it so that for each $v \in U$ you can find $\phi \in V^*$ and $\epsilon > 0$ so that $\mathcal{N}_{\phi, v, \epsilon} \subseteq U$. Then you know that the topology is generated by that since if $U$ is an open set in the weak topology then you can write $U = \bigcup_{v \in U} N_{v,\phi,\epsilon}$ for some $\phi \in V^*$ and $\epsilon > 0$ depending on $v$, which means that $U$ is open in the topology generated by the $\mathcal{N}_{\phi, v, \epsilon}.$

Comment: Slight correction -- you are done if you know that $\mathcal{N}_{\phi,v,\epsilon}$ is open in the weak topology, but that is easy.